# How to write unit test for a method in a class but not call the constructor i the class in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, interface, moq, inversion-of-control

I want to unit test `MethodA` in `class A`. However, I don't really want to call `MethodB` when constructing `A`, as it takes a lot of time to process.

Is there any way to deal with it?
`MethodB` is required to be called before anything else, so I can't move it out of the ctor (it initializes the `listA`, `listB` and `listC` fields).

I don't know how to use a mocking framework for this.

```
public Class A {

  List<int> listA;
  List<int> listB;
  List<int> listC;


  public A()
  {     
     MethodB();    // Long processing.
  }


  public List<int> GetA()
  {
      return listA;
  } 

  public List<int> GetB()
  {
      return listB;
  } 

  public List<int> GetC()
  {
      return listC;
  } 

  private void MethodB()
  {
      // Expensive initialization of list fields.
  }

  public bool MethodA(customerCollection foo)
  {
        for (int i = 0; i < customerCollection .Count; i++)
        {
            if (customerCollection[i].Name == "Something")
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

      return false;

  }
}
```

Comment: If it's in your constructor you can't not call it.

Comment: Your `MethodA` makes no sense - you're using `customerCollection` both as a type and as a variable.

Comment: Also consider refactoring the code to 1) use properties for `list` getters and 2) use a LINQ query in `MethodA` which will be a lot shorter and harder to make a mistake in.

Comment: From the detail you have provided, it appears to me like method `A` has no business being inside class `A`. If you properly isolate your concerns, you should be able to test method `A` without going through costly initialization. Consider extracting it into a helper class or something of the sort.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can see your `MethodA` does not require an `A` instance to function, so you could just change it to be `static` and test it without an `A` instance. But please note that from an OOP point of view this method has no place inside the `A` class (Single Responsibilty Principle), so you're in need of some refactoring.

Comment: I agree. This is one way of solving it. I had suggested extracting the method into a helper class on a comment for the same reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is prety clear that `MethodA` can be `static`, it doesn't use any of the `class` fields I would propose different approach because question is marked with **moq** and **inversion-of-control** tags. A bit of the redesign and you can archive that... For example you could expose the lists through the `IRepository` interface and then you can leverage IoC principle which enable mocking within your unit tests. Something like this:

```
public interface IRepository
{
    void Init();
    IList<int> Get();
}

public Class A 
{    
  IRepository _aRepository;
  IRepository _bRepository;
  IRepository _cRepository;

  public A(IRepository aRepository, IRepository bRepository, IRepository bRepository)
  {
    _aRepository = aRepository;
    _bRepository = bRepository;
    _cRepository = cRepository;

     MethodB();
  }

  public IList<int> GetA()
  {
      return _aRepository.Get();
  } 

  public IList<int> GetB()
  {
      return _bRepository.Get();
  } 

  public IList<int> GetC()
  {
      return _cRepository.Get();
  } 

  private void MethodB()
  {
      _aRepository.Init();
      _bRepository.Init();
      _cRepository.Init();
  }

  public bool MethodA(customerCollection foo){...whatever...}
}
```

then within unit test you can mock your repositories and leverage Moq library

```
Mock<IRepository> aRepositoryMock = new Mock<IRepository>();
Mock<IRepository> bRepositoryMock = new Mock<IRepository>();
Mock<IRepository> cRepositoryMock = new Mock<IRepository>();

aRepositoryMock.Setup(m => m.Init)...setup Callback for example
aRepositoryMock.Setup(m => m.Get()).Returns(...some list...)

...aslo you can setup b and c repositories...

var sut = new A(aRepositoryMock.Object, bRepositoryMock.Object, cRepositoryMock.Object);
```